# selecting drive letter in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

All,

This one is about selecting a drive letter in a powershell script. The method i picked up from searching through Stackoverflow was :
`ls function:[efiklmnopqrtuvwxy]: -n|?{!(test-path $_)}|random`

For me listing all the characters as the eligible candidate dosn't look nice. Is there a better efficient way of doing it in a one liner?
something like `[efiklmnopqr[t-y]]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're in PowerShell already, do you even need a drive letter? `New-PSDrive` allows you to use any string as a drive (e.g. `$Env:Userprofile` is mapped to `Home:` for me).

Answer (score 0):

List all possibilities and exclude undesired ones with `-notmatch` regex. Like so,

```
# Filter drive letters from D..Q and pick one at random
ls function:[a-z]:|?{ $_.name -notmatch "[d-q]"} -n|?{!(test-path $_)}|random
```